# align 0 in the same line in lattice

Tags: r, ggplot2, lattice

This is the code for `ggplot2`

```
library(ggplot2)

test <- data.frame(a=c('1','1','2','2'),b=c(2,-2,4,-3),d=c('m','n','m','n')) 

p <- ggplot(test,aes(a,b))

p + geom_bar(position=position_dodge(),stat='identity',
             fill='deeppink',colour='black',width=0.5)
```

[image: ggplot]

for some reason, I need to re-draw the figure with `lattice`,

```
library(lattice)

a<-barchart(b~a,data=test)
```

[image: lattice]

so I want the same alignment as in `ggplot2` by using `lattice`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can get what you want simply with a stacked barchart.

```
library(lattice)
barchart(b~a, data=test, col=c("#00FFFF"), group=d, stack=TRUE)
```

[image]