# align 0 in the same line in lattice (2)

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

I have asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385686/) where I could use `stack=T` to solve my problem.

However, when I introduce another factor, `stack=T` is not working.

Please see this example:

```
test <- data.frame(a=c(rep('x', 4),rep('y',4)),
                   b=c(2,-2,4,-3,5,-1,3,-5),
                   d=c('m','m','n','n','m','m','n','n')) 

barchart(b~a, data=test, col=c("#00FFFF"), stack=TRUE,group=d)
```

[image: barchart1]

but I want to get something like this:

```
barchart(b~a, data=test, col=c("#00FFFF"), stack=F,group=d)
```

[image: barchart2]

and at the same time, align 0 in the same line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

barchart(b~a, data=test, col=c("#00FFFF"), stack=F,group=d, origin=0)

Comment: just add origin=0 will be ok.